# What loss function should one use when using an RNN to to predict a time series of binary values which are not necessarily independent?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, independence, loss-functions, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to use an RNN to predict a time series {$y_t$}, where $y_t \in {0,1} \forall 1 \leq t \leq T$  given an input time series {$x_t$}. The elements of the target sequence are not necessarily independent. Which distributions would be a good model of this output? Ultimately, I want to use this distribution over the target time series to derive a loss for the input-output sequence pair. I know of binary cross entropy with logits but this makes the assumption of independence between the elements of the target sequence.

Comment: Does it make that assumption? I think you could just use any of the standard [propse scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info), and dependence comes in as the observation that models that *do* account for dependence should perform better than models that do not do so. At least, scoring rules are used all the time in this way in general time series forecasting (see papers by Gneiting), so I don't quite see why there should be a difference in the binary case.

Comment: You could try to incorporate an autoregressive component within $y_t$. It depends on what you are trying to do though. We need more information about the problem to help.